# Cannot configure node group in new EKS cluster due to no Node IAM role found

Tags: aws-iam, role-based-access-control, eks

I've created a new EKS cluster, and am trying to add a new node group to it.

I'm stuck on selecting a Node IAM Role from the dropdown.

[image: node]

I followed the link, and created all options for roles I could see fit, still none appear in the dropdown.

[image: roles]

Note: currently I don't really care about restricting access, I'm only trying to run some POC against EKS with a test account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually pretty well described in the docs.

> Before you create worker nodes, you must create an IAM role with the
> following IAM policies:
>
> AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
>
> AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
>
> AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly

Also you need to make sure that this role could be assumed by EKS.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: update the policy under "Trust Relationships".

Comment: Technically the role gets assumed by EC2 rather than EKS. Having said that I'm still having the issue the OP described even after following the documentation (and double checking with your answer). There must be something else somewhere that causes a problem with this in some situations...

Comment: Ah... the refresh button next to the role list only _pretends_ to refresh the roles. You have to actually hard refresh the page to see newly created roles. ‍♂️